# How to get a Facebook Auth token in Node with Only Username and Password

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have the following (dummy data) data.

`AppId=000000000001`
`FB-email=myEmail@email.com`
`FB-password=passw0rd`

I have a Node script like so.

```
var request = require('request')
request.post({'...'},function(facebookAuthToken){
   // facebook auth token is here
})
```

In other words, I'm trying to log in to Facebook using Node with only a username and password. How can it be done?

Comment: You can't. Facebook forbids using the username/password directly like this, and puts obstacles like captchas in the way of automated attempts to use them.

Comment: @ceejayoz Good to know. Do you have any articles / further reading on the matter?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ "Don’t proxy, request or collect Facebook usernames or passwords."

Comment: Why would you even do it?